# GlobalProtect VPN blocks port 443 on a remote server when installed and logged in

Tags: vpn

So besides the act of signing into a company VPN, the internals of the system have been hidden from me.  I have a problem which in my case I need to explain to get an idea of where to start.

I've set up a Ubuntu VSI on version 20.0 with an ssl cert and runs Nginx/Python and works perfectly through port 443.  And of course I could ping the server's IP address

However, once I installed `globalprotect` (version 5.3.1.0-36) and successfully signed in, I found that I could still ping the server, but couldn't reach the website anymore.

I have verified this by switching the VPN on/off.  My questions are:

1. how would I monitor or "catch" what the VPN is doing?
2. can this be overwritten/overridden somehow?

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to answer your questions as it is unclear which OS you are using.

Comment: edited - it's a Ubuntu 20.0 server